# How can I update only changed values from another table in PostgreSQL 9.4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have this query but updates the whole region_tmp table, which I dont want to, I only need to update a row in region table if anything has changed. I know  I can specify which row with the regionid but am looking for something more general since I have a lot of records.

```
UPDATE REGION_TMP t SET
      REGIONID=R.REGIONID,
      REGIONDESCRIPTION=R.REGIONDESCRIPTION
FROM REGION R
WHERE R.REGIONID = T.REGIONID;
```

REGION TABLE:

| REGIONID | REGIONDESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AMERICA |
| 2 | EUROPE |
| 3 | ASIA |

REGION_TMP TABLE:

| REGIONID | REGIONDESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AMERICA |
| 2 | EUROPE |
| 3 | AFRICA |

My desire output in REGION_TMP:

| REGIONID | REGIONDESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AMERICA |
| 2 | EUROPE |
| 3 | ASIA |

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to create a duplicate of your *REGION* table, but you already have a *REGION_TMP* table, so you just want to update the values that do not match.

In order to achieve that, you need to join the two tables inside the `UPDATE` statement and replace the values of `REGION_TMP.REGIONDESCRIPTION` with the corresponding `REGION.REGIONDESCRIPTION` where the `REGION_ID` applies for both and the `REGIONDESCRIPTION` is different:

```
UPDATE REGION_TMP
SET REGIONDESCRIPTION = REGION.REGIONDESCRIPTION
FROM REGION
WHERE REGION_TMP.REGIONID = REGION.REGIONID
  AND REGION_TMP.REGIONDESCRIPTION <> REGION.REGIONDESCRIPTION;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oATTuZuPpVFvwty7VBThpE/3).